# Question about the highlighted part of the following passage

Tags: word-meaning

> **Event and interval from vaccination**
>
> A. Anaphylaxis anaphylactic shock (7 days )
>
> B. Brachial neuritis ( 28 days )
>
> C. Any acute complications or sequelae (including death) of above events (**interval - not applicable**)
>
> D. Events described in manufacturer's package insert as contraindications to additional doses of vaccine (**interval - see package insert**)

When it says **interval** not applicable. What do they mean by saying **interval**? It should mean stop  or pause. But what does it mean in this context? I know that it is very hard to grasp, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the title

> **Event and interval from vaccination**

An **interval of time** is a **period of time**

the two examples **A** and **B** show number of days as the **interval**

The **interval** is the time **from when** the vaccination was given **to when** the symptom may show up.

> A. Anaphylaxis anaphylactic shock (**7 days**)

Anaphylactic shock may show up within **7 days**, after which the probability of occurrence diminishes.

> C. Any acute complications or sequelae (including death) of above events (**interval - not applicable**)

**interval - not applicable** means complications could show up at **any time**

This use of **interval** should not be confused with the BrE meaning of **interval** which is an **intermission** (AmE) between parts of a performance.